# RPC calls in OpenStack

Tags: rpc, openstack, openstack-nova

How RPC calls are implemented between modules of OpenStack specially Nova and Neutron?
I want to call a neutron method in Nova through RPC.

Searched throughout the web, but couldn't find any easy understandable explanation.
Any link/document would be helpful.

Comment: You can't really call a method unless it's in the supported API.  However, you might look at the python clients as you can import methods from those clients which provide a bit of an abstraction layer to the REST APIs of the openstack services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two aspects:

1. RPC among components of a single openstack module. Take Nova for example, AMQP is underneath RPC implementation in pub/sub paradigm. Refer [AMQP and Nova](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/rpc.html)
2. RPC among openstack modules. It is the communication across different modules to serve user requests like how nova, glance and neutron work together when booting a virtual machine. it uses exposed module API to do inter-module communication. for example, it depends on both Neutron API client and Glance API client in nova.

Comment: Thanks @shawnzhu for the clarification on the RPC calls.